# Django tests - simulate that user is logged in

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

In my tests I have a following bit of code:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client.defaults['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(
        '{username}:{password}'.format(**self.login_data)
    )

def test_list_view(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('data_list'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

My problem is that this check has to go through basic http authentication which uses ldap and it's pretty slow.

Is there a way I can simulate that user is logged in?

Comment: Why you don't use `self.client.login(username='fred', password='secret')`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login

Comment: mock the server using monkey patching

Comment: @Mounir because I have implemented basic http authentication and I have to use other way to login.

Comment: @arpit how to do that?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/monkeypatching-for-humans/ Here is the post how to do that

Answer (score 2):

You should create user because tests create test database (not your) everytime.

```
User.objects.create_user(username=<client_username>, password=<client_password>)
```

Now create Client and login

```
self.c = django.test.client.Client()
self.c.login(username=<client_username>, password=<client_password>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override request headers for every client request like this example:

```
def test_report_wrong_password(self):
    headers = dict()
    headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode('user_name:password')
    response = self.client.post(
        '/report/',
        content_type='application/json',
        data=json.dumps(JSON_DATA),
        **headers)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)
```